# What is a Single Objective Optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, definition, problem-solving

I can't find any definition of this problem on the Internet. Could you help me by providing some definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single objective would be the oppositie of multi-objective optimization. In other words, standard optimization with a single objective function. Multi-objective optimization means optimization with several competing objectives.